How can I find out the temp table size which is created by a sql in MySQL
Hi we all know the tmp_table_size in MySQL is 16mb, but how can I find out what the size of temp table that one sql produce in MySQL?
I have searched on Google, but only find the fixed variable tmp_table_size of MySQL, I just want to know what the size of only one SQL produce. thanks!
